# Unable to sign in to office 365 due to cookie issue

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, cookies

I am trying to sign in to a locally installed powerpoint

[image]

I entered my email and then this error message comes up

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

The following screenshot shows  my IE settings at the moment. The setting available for 'Internet' is 'High' only.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to disable 'Turn on Pop-up Blocker'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

internet explorer>tools>internet options>privacy>sites>remove all option to remove all the existing websites.

This method should work, it worked for me.

windows 10 user.

Comment: OP had already accepted an answer

Answer (score -1):

Funnily enough, this seems to be a cookie issue.

Clearing cookies according to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-microsoft-edge-login-says-cookies-are/904d28ab-bda8-4d2f-b4f5-dac01aa865ab did fix the issue for me.